Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) Django 4.1
I was trying to add a chatbot (dialogflow) to my current Django webpage. However, I encounter a problem. I get this message: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /.
My first attempt at finding out the problem was to comment the following line in settings.py:
django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware

And got this message:
Method Not Allowed (POST)
So I thought, that my post routing was wrong.
I was testing using Postman:

Then got the following result:

I will add my github with how the files are exactly located. My guess is that my routing is wrong but the other files work perfectly.food_website
My post request using POSTMAN is the yellow which gives me an answer and the blue is the post request from dialogflow website.


Do you include the CSRF token in your request? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/csrf/

Since I am using React, I am not using that template system. In the frontend, so I am using middleware = django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware

Did you try setting the view with csrf_exempt decorator?

@JPG yes, and I also tried ensure_csrf_cookie decorator.

When you are using the middleware, you are expected to include the CSRF token in any POST request. If you don't include the token, you get the error CSRF cookie not set. please read the docs that I have linked for how to include the token from a cookie in AJAX requests.

You seem to be sending the request to the wrong URL - you're sending it at the root instead of api/chatbot/webhook/.

I fixed it, the correct webhook URL is crucial for Dialogflow to successfully send requests to your Django backend. I had to set the URL to your ngrok URL + your webhook path. In my case: ngrok.io/api/chatbot/webhook/ in the dialog webhook
